# If you DONT use noac when mounting, is there a command to refresh the file and directory attributes given a path

Tags: linux, mount, nfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can NFS be forced to refresh stale files/directories when not using noac on the mount?](https://serverfault.com/questions/443843/can-nfs-be-forced-to-refresh-stale-files-directories-when-not-using-noac-on-the)

I may be asking this question in the wrong place.

We mount without using noac.  I have a file that I append to once every 20 minutes.  Then it will be read with mmap about 5,000 times a minute.  We only mmap a couple blocks for each read.  Needless to say, noac just kills the access performance, so we don't use it.

I add data to the end of the file using a mount with noac and read from a mount without noac.  The mounts that are reading are not seeing the new data.

I want to know if there is a command I can execute from c to refresh the attributes of a path and all its files.

**EDIT:**
I should add we cannot mount and unmount since there are 16 servers running on each system and they are constantly accessing the files.

thanks!

Comment: We had some interesting problems a few years ago with Java mmapping jar files, then failing to "let go" and re-read the file when the map got marked dirty.  Our solution?  Kill off Java entirely and restart it.  Hope you find a better solution.  :)